# How to add slideshow property to the Roku app homepage banner?

Tags: carousel, slideshow, banner, homescreen, roku

After the discontinuation of roSlideShow component in BrightScript is there any alternative to add slideshow / carousel feature to my Roku app homepage banner? Please share your answers regarding this query.